# Python Tkinter Problem (with global keyword)

Tags: python, tkinter, global, keyword

I have given two files in Python:

file1.py:

```
from file2 import *

root = None

create_window_middle(400, 400)

label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 1")
label1.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 2")
label2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

file2.py:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_window_middle(x, y):
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    geometry_x = x
    geometry_y = y
    monitor_center_x = root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - (geometry_x / 2)
    monitor_center_y = root.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - (geometry_y / 2)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (geometry_x, geometry_y, monitor_center_x, monitor_center_y))
```

Why does this not work? According to my logic, I define the variable root in File1.

Then I call the function create_window_middle, in which I write global root. Thereby I should be able to change the global root object within the function, which I try to do in the next line by overwriting the None with tk.Tk().

But apparently the global variable root in file1 is not overwritten with the tk object. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Globals are separate for each file.  You would need to return `root` from the second file's function if you wanted to use it in the first file.

Answer (score 1):

@jasonharper 's comment gives the answer, but I can expand a little.

The `global` marker makes a variable referenced inside a function refer to the variable of the same name within the module. The module scope is the highest in  python, and there is no truly universal global scope.

Please also read the docs about [global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) and how to [share variables between modules](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)

You could, for example, have done the following:

```
import file2
file2.create_window_middle(400, 400)
label1 = tk.Label(file2.root, text="Label 1")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

- In file1. You need to call `file2` for a function and add a `root` to
  the function. And add `.configure` for each `Label`.
- In file 2. Add `global` inside function and add a widget to the
  function parameters.

Snippet:

file1.py:

```
import  file2 
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

file2.create_window_middle(root, 200, 200)


label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 1")
label1.configure(text=p2._x)
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="Label 2")
label2.configure(text=p2._y)
label2.pack()
 
root.mainloop()
```

file2.py:

```
def create_window_middle(widget, x, y):
    global _x
    global _y
    
    geometry_x = x
    geometry_y = y
    _x = monitor_center_x = widget.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - (geometry_x / 2)
    _y = monitor_center_y = widget.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - (geometry_y / 2)
```

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use eval() function:

```
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
root.mainloop()
```